# How to get domain url in Django?

Tags: django, nginx

I want to get domain url to use in view of Django and I use Nginx in my server but I got a problem:

I have tried

> request.META['HTTP_HOST']

or

> request.build_absolute_uri

but it only return 127.0.0.1:8000 (proxy pass in nginx config to Django project). So are there any solution for this?

Thanks in advance.